# Machine Learning Question Regarding this method

Tags: python, machine-learning, methods, pytorch

This is my current code. I understand the `in_size` and `out_size` are the sizes of the input and output layers respectively. However, what does the `self` parameter indicate and what is `super().__init__()` used for?

```
class MnistModel(nn.Module):
    """Feedfoward neural network with 1 hidden layer"""
    def __init__(self, in_size, out_size):
        super().__init__()
        # hidden layer
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(in_size, 16)
        # hidden layer 2
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(16, 32)
        # output layer
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(32, out_size)
```

Comment: what language background are you coming from? [This tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) could be your first stopping point

Comment: Does this answer your question? [understanding python super with init methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods)

Comment: These are basic questions about a language that you should learn by reading a book or taking a course about python.